# QComBox in Qt, personalize the items

Tags: qt, qcombobox

In Qt, I want to add for each item in `QComBox` a short item string. That means when I choose an item in `QComBox`, I want to show the corresponding short item string instead of the selected item string.

For example, 
for a `QComBox`. I add items "aaa", "bbb", and for "aaa" I set a short string named "a", also "b" for "bbb"
When I choose "aaa", I want the "a" to be shown in the field instead of "aaa".

And also I want the items not editable just like standard `QComBox`, I mean the appearance should be the same as the non editable `QComBox`. 
How to implement this behavior in Qt, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The idea is to set custom item deledate for the combo box's dropdown menu so that it uses other data to display. "a" and "b" will be main item text, "aaa" and "bbb" will be assigned to `Qt::UserRole`. Working example:

```
class MyItemDelegate : public QStyledItemDelegate {
  Q_OBJECT
public:
  MyItemDelegate() {
    fake_model.setColumnCount(1);
    fake_model.setRowCount(1);
    fake_model.setItem(0, 0, new QStandardItem());
  }

  void paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, 
             const QModelIndex &index) const {
    fake_model.item(0, 0)->setText(index.data(Qt::UserRole).toString());
    QStyledItemDelegate::paint(painter, option, fake_model.index(0, 0));
  }

private:
  QStandardItemModel fake_model;
};

//...
ui->comboBox->addItem("a", "aaa");
ui->comboBox->addItem("b", "bbb");
ui->comboBox->setItemDelegate(new MyItemDelegate());
```

If you want to user `UserRole` for something else, you can switch to another role: use `ui->comboBox->setItemData(0, "aaa", otherRole)` for setting data and change role in the `paint` method implementation.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to manipulate delegades, as proposed by [Pavel Strakhov](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22584471/1035613). Delegates are need only when you want very specific customization of viewed items. In your case it's enough to manipulate data model of QComboBox:

```
// Adding item:
void addItem( QComboBox *cb, const QString& name, const QString& userData )
{
  QStandardItemModel *model = qobject_cast< QStandardItemModel * >( cb->model() );
  QStandardItem *newItem = new QStandardItem();
  newItem->setData( name, Qt::DisplayRole );
  newItem->setData( userData , Qt::UserRole );
  model->appendRow( newItem );
}

// Getting item data
void getItemData( QComboBox *cb, const int index, QString& name, QString& userData )
{
  QStandardItemModel *model = qobject_cast< QStandardItemModel * >( cb->model() );
  QStandardItem *item = model->item( index );
  name = item ->data( name, Qt::DisplayRole ).toString();
  userData = item ->data( Qt::UserRole ).toString();
}
```

It is good practice to use [Qt MVC](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/model-view-programming.html) there. You will have a lot of extra features, like disabling items, adding checkboxes, changing font etc.

You need to add data validation for my sample (checking pointers / indexes). I just want to show main idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can derive your own combo box class from QComboBox and overwrite the functions such that it opens a custom menu for selection. In this custom menu you can use different names for the items than in the ComboBox itself. So the QCombobox would hold items "a", "b", etc. while in the menu you create entries "aaa", "bbb". The logic that connects "a" to "aaa" is your job, but it is easy. You can just use the index of the items.

Here is an example where this idea is implemented for a different reason:
http://svn.gerbilvis.org/wsvn/Gerbil/gui/widgets/ahcombobox.h
http://svn.gerbilvis.org/wsvn/Gerbil/gui/widgets/ahcombobox.cpp

The behavior of the combobox is slightly different to the classical one, but usability is the same. In some cases QComboBox uses a menu like this to display, in other cases it does a dropdown. With this method, it's just always a menu.